# How can I convert Jquery code to React JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to implement a drag and drop functionality using React, now I am trying to reverse engineer the jquery code to achieve this functionality. Any ideas?

`
// drag and drop effects

```
$("ul").on("dragstart","li",function(event){
    $(this).css("opacity", 0.4);
    dragElement = $(this);
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', $(this).html());
});

$("ul").on("dragenter","li",function(){
    $(this).addClass("over");
});

$("ul").on("dragleave","li",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});


$("ul").on("dragover","li",function(event){
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }
   event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
   return false;
});

// drag and drop handle

$("ul").on("drop","li",function(event){
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
      event.stopPropagation(); 
    }

   if (dragElement != $(this)) {
     $(dragElement).html($(this).html())
     dragElement.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
     this.innerHTML = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  }
  return false;
});

$("ul").on("dragend","li",function(){`enter code here`
    $("ul li").removeClass("over");
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});


`
```

Comment: Do you have a React starting point you could share, even if it is not working yet?

Comment: I want to make this todo drag and dropable without using a library https://github.com/socishe/react-todo-list

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this, but I would start by modifying your code in TodoList.js to detect the mouse down, mouse up and mouse move on the <Todo> elements. After this, I would try to sort out the logic to move the element accordingly during the drag and change the item's position in the list once the mouseup happens.

I would probably not go with the `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer` used here, because React will probably lose track of the element.